# Generate multiple donut charts from a dataset with Google Chart

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

I have [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEU2g.png) made using `jChartFX`.

[image]

Here is the code to generate this chart:

```
$scope.funcTypePersonQuantity = function() {
  $http.get($scope.UrlData).success(function(data, status) {
    var res = angular.fromJson(data);
    res = angular.fromJson(res.result[0]);

    var crosstabSuport = new cfx.data.CrosstabDataProvider();
    crosstabSuport.setDataSource(res);
    crosstabSuport.getRows().setHeading("PERSON");
    crosstabSuport.getColumns().setHeading("TYPE");
    crosstabSuport.setValueName("QUANTITY");
    chart1.setDataSource(crosstabSuport);

    var crosstabSuport2 = new cfx.data.CrosstabDataProvider();
    crosstabSuport2.setDataSource(res);
    crosstabSuport2.getRows().setHeading("TYPE");
    crosstabSuport2.getColumns().setHeading("PERSON");
    crosstabSuport2.setValueName("QUANTITY");
    chart2.setDataSource(crosstabSuport2);
  });
};
```

I wonder if it's possible to do the same with [`Google Chart`](https://developers.google.com/chart). I generated several charts (pizza, donuts, bar, etc) but individually. I need to automatically generate multiple charts from a dataset that comes in `jSON`, as in`jChartsFX`.

This is the structure of the data in `jSON`:

```
{
  "cols": [
    {"id":"type","label":"Type","pattern":"","type":"string"},
    {"id":"persons","label":"Person","pattern":"","type":"string"},
    {"id":"quantity","label":"Quantity","pattern":"","type":"number"}
  ], 
  "rows": [
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":229,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":354,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":13,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":149,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":51,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":8,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":52,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":13,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":35,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":11,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":10,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":6,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":4,"f":null}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":6,"f":null}]},
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using google's [`ChartWrapper` class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapper-class) from the `'controls'` package,

you can set a `view` over the data table,
to use only certain columns...

```
var chart0 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'PieChart',
  containerId: 'chart_div0',
  dataTable: data,
  options: {
    height: 300,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    pieHole: 0.25,
    title: data.getColumnLabel(0)
  },

  // use Type and Quantity columns
  view: {
    columns: [0, 2]
  }
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols": [
      {"id":"type","label":"Type","pattern":"","type":"string"},
      {"id":"persons","label":"Person","pattern":"","type":"string"},
      {"id":"quantity","label":"Quantity","pattern":"","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows": [
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":229,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":354,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":13,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":149,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":51,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":8,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":52,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":13,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":35,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":11,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":10,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":6,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":4,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":6,"f":null}]},
    ]
  });

  var chart0 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div0',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      height: 300,
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      pieHole: 0.25,
      title: data.getColumnLabel(0)
    },
    view: {
      columns: [0, 2]
    }
  });
  chart0.draw();

  var chart1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div1',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      height: 300,
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      pieHole: 0.25,
      title: data.getColumnLabel(1)
    },
    view: {
      columns: [1, 2]
    }
  });
  chart1.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div0"></div>
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
```

---

however, as seen in the above snippet,
the data presented in the question is not aggregated,
so you will end up with multiple slices per type or person

3 slices for `"Type 1"`, etc...

the `group()` method can be used to aggregate the data

in this case, the `group()` method would need to be used twice,
once for each "group by" column

see following working snippet...

note: `ChartWrapper` not required here, could use --> `google.visualization.PieChart`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols": [
      {"id":"type","label":"Type","pattern":"","type":"string"},
      {"id":"persons","label":"Person","pattern":"","type":"string"},
      {"id":"quantity","label":"Quantity","pattern":"","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows": [
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":229,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":354,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":13,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":149,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":51,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":8,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":52,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":13,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":35,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":11,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":10,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":6,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":4,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":6,"f":null}]},
    ]
  });

  var groupData0 = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [0],
    [{
      column: 2,
      type: 'number',
      label: data.getColumnLabel(2),
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
    }]
  );

  var chart0 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div0',
    dataTable: groupData0,
    options: {
      height: 300,
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      pieHole: 0.25,
      title: data.getColumnLabel(0)
    }
  });
  chart0.draw();

  var groupData1 = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [1],
    [{
      column: 2,
      type: 'number',
      label: data.getColumnLabel(2),
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
    }]
  );

  var chart1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div1',
    dataTable: groupData1,
    options: {
      height: 300,
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      pieHole: 0.25,
      title: data.getColumnLabel(1)
    }
  });
  chart1.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div0"></div>
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
```

---

you can also use the [`DataView` class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) to separate columns...

```
var view0 = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view0.setColumns([0, 2]);

var chart0 = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);
chart0.draw(view0, options);

var view1 = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view1.setColumns([1, 2]);
...
```

---

**EDIT**

the view has keys for both `columns` and `rows`...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols": [
      {"id":"type","label":"Type","pattern":"","type":"string"},
      {"id":"persons","label":"Person","pattern":"","type":"string"},
      {"id":"quantity","label":"Quantity","pattern":"","type":"number"}
    ],
    "rows": [
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":229,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 1","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":354,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":13,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":149,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 2","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":51,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":8,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 3","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":52,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":13,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":35,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 4","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":11,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":10,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 5","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":6,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 6","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 1","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 2","f":null},{"v":4,"f":null}]},
      {"c":[{"v":"Type 7","f":null},{"v":"Person 3","f":null},{"v":6,"f":null}]},
    ]
  });

  var chartPerson3 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'PieChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div0',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      height: 300,
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      pieHole: 0.25,
      title: 'Person 3'
    },
    view: {
      columns: [0, 2],
      rows: data.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: 'Person 3'}])
    }
  });
  chartPerson3.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div0"></div>
```

and `DataView` has methods for both...

`setColumns`
`setRows`

Comment: I need it to show one graphic per person and that each color is a type, like in the image I put

Comment: Sorry, I changed the image.

Comment: changed __EDIT__ above to pull the `rows` for the `view` using `getFilteredRows`...

Comment: Is it possible to display only one person per chart?

Comment: It's not exactly the solution I wanted, but it does not seem to work with Google Chart. I'll mark it anyway because it was the closest I could get.