# Google Visualisation Api dashboard showing specific column values in piecharts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a created a dashboard from an sql query it is 90 columns and 500+ rows, I can display it all in a table but now I want to make pie charts displaying specific column data.

For example I have two columns 3 'gender' and 71 'revenue'. I have been trying to get the pie chart to show for each distinct gender and the total revenue generated, but for the life of me can not figure it out.

I am hoping to use the same datatable as the dashboard for filtering to work but have been completely stuck for a while now and couldn't find anything in google documentation, any help is greatly appreciated.

This will let me show each entry with its gender and revenue individually:

```
       var   genderFund = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            'chartType': 'PieChart',
            'containerId': 'chart_div',
            'options': {
                'width': 300,
                'height': 300,
                'pieSliceText': 'value',
            },
            'view': {'columns': [3, 71]}
                     // is it possible to group distinct columns
        });
```

Comment: you can use the [group()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) method to summarize the data for the pie chart -- check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44187719/5090771)

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks for the reply, I've got the grouped data working although seems to not work too well with using the dashboard datatable, I've used an event listener for the filters and that seems to work alright with just generating seperate charts instead of a dashboard.